# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData crashing when data value is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1, iOS 12.1+, Swift 5

The function below is supposed to read an archived value and return it.
You can see the previous code that worked (unarchiveObject) until it was deprecated.

The code works as long as the returned value for 'data' is not nil - meaning that a value has previously been saved.
However, in a new installation of the app, this crashes since the value had not been previously saved.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Since I do not want to preload values, what is the correct way to write this function so that it does not crash?

(It also appears that NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData is now deprecated as well with iOS 12+. What would be the correct replacement?)

```
func color(forKey defaultName: String) -> UIColor? {
    var color: UIColor?
    // Working code prior to Swift 5 and iOS 12
    //        if let colorData = data(forKey: defaultName) {
    //            color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
    //        }

    // Works unless NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data(forKey: defaultName)!) returns nil
    do {
        if let colorData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data(forKey: defaultName)!) as? UIColor {
            color = colorData
        }
    } catch {
        //print("Couldn't read file.")
    }
    return color
}
```

Comment: You solve it like you do for any optional that shouldn't be forced-unwrapped.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how that would work for type data as a UIColor - can you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the replacement of `unarchiveObject(with:)` for this case is [`unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2983380-unarchivedobject).

Second of all just do the same optional binding like in *Working code prior to Swift 5 and iOS 12*:

```
func color(forKey defaultName: String) -> UIColor? {
    guard let colorData = data(forKey: defaultName) else { return nil }
    return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)
}
```

Comment: If I replace with 'unarchivedObject', won't I still have the deprecation to deal with?

Comment: @wayneh No, `unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)` is not deprecated, just the opposite, it's the modern way. You asked what was the correct replacement and you were told the answer.

Comment: @matt - I found this page which indicates it is deprecated (or I'm reading it all wrong?) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/1413189-archiveddata

Comment: You are indeed reading it all wrong. You've been given a link in vadian's answer. Click it!

Comment: @matt - DUH! :)